# MongoDB / Pymongo Query with Datetime

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I am trying to retrieve the data I have inserted into mongodb via pymongo.

My code for insert is below (after parsing via regex)

```
if connection is not None:
    db.model.insert({"time": datetime.datetime(int(int3), int(int1),
                                               int(int2), int(int4),
                                               int(int5), int(int6),
                                               int(int7))})
```

I then entered two data points in the shell.

```
>>> start = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 6, 35, 6, 764)
>>> end = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 6, 55, 3, 381)
```

I then tried to query the range of data between these two data points and received what is returned.

```
>>> db.wing_model.find({'time': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}})
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0301CFD0>
>>> db.wing_model.find({'time': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}})
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0301C110>
```

Data is listed below.

```
[02/02/2012 06:32:07.334][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:07.334][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:07.334][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:13.711][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:13.711][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:13.711][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:22.473][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:22.473][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:32:22.473][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:35:06.764][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:35:06.765][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:35:06.765][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:54:52.008][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:54:52.008][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:54:52.008][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:54:59.512][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:54:59.512][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:54:59.512][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:03.381][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:03.381][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:03.381][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:06.142][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:06.142][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:06.142][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:09.652][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:09.652][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:09.652][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:13.396][INFO]
[02/02/2012 06:55:13.396][INFO]
```

How do I get my query to return everything between the 'start' and 'end' data?

Also, how do I receive this in an intelligible form?

Finally, why does the same query return different cursor object locations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Repeating existing basic tutorial documentation:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 6, 35, 6, 764)
end = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 6, 55, 3, 381)

for doc in db.wing_model.find({'time': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}}):
    print doc
```

> Finally, why does the same query return different cursor object
>   locations?

Where should that be the case?

You see two different cursor instances which will likely return the same result set - or?

Comment: I have done this. It returns as 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' highlighting doc.

Comment: And where exactly? If you are using Python 3 then you need of course print() - but we must not guess your environment. So think about what you are doing for blindly using code.

Comment: nevermind. I forgot the parens the whole time... You were helpful. Thank you. if you could, can you tell me how to extract one part of the query and insert it into a python array? It seems like I have to parse it again if I wanted to do that.

Comment: Does not work with Python 3.6.7 - bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: {datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 16, 14, 13, 2, 392578)

Answer (score -2):

```
@staticmethod
def _get_results_to_json(data):
    """Get documents from a MongoDB search result.
    Transforms MongoDB BSON documents into JSON serializable documents.
    This process converts the ObjectIds into hexadecimal strings.
    Parameters
    ----------
    data : `~pymongo.cursor.Cursor`
        A MongoDB search result.
    Returns
    -------
    |list| of |dict|
        A list of JSON serializable documents.
    """
    if isinstance(data, Cursor):
        data = list(data)

    if isinstance(data, list):
        for doc in data:
            doc['_id'] = str(doc['_id'])
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        data['_id'] = str(data['_id'])

    return data

_get_results_to_json(db.wing_model.find({'time': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}}))
```