# Filter objects between two dates in django with MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

I am building RestApi using django and mongoDB, so I am trying to filter the objects that I have in the DB by two dates.

Assume that the user inserted two dates, one is (from) second is (to), I want to return all the objects in my DB that is between these two dates.

Here is my models:

```
class BsfCall(models.Model):

CallID = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
deadlineDate = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
organizationName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
information = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
areaOfResearch = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.organizationName
```

**deadlineDate** is storing the date in this format **(day/month/year)**

How can I return the objects between these dates, for example I made this method but I was not able to complete it:

```
def get_bsf_call_by_dates(first_date, second_date):

from_date = datetime.strptime(first_date, "%d/%m/%y")
to_date = datetime.strptime(second_date, "%d/%m/%y")
```

Thanks A lot...

Comment: Have a look at: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: See this post: [MongoDB / Pymongo Query with Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957595/mongodb-pymongo-query-with-datetime). Generally, this is a date range query.